# Clean up an existing project

Tags: ios, xcode

My App is written in swift and already available on the App-Store. But this is a very old App and I want to completely redesign it. So the whole architecture and design will change. Because of such a big change I want to throw all the files and classes away. But there are also different targets, many Pods, lots of Build rules and so on.
So my question is, is there a way to clean up my existing project so there is no old stuff anymore?
I considered to make a new Branch and then throw it all away. But is this a good solution?

I dont want to make a new project because when I finally upload the new version to the App-Store the users can simply update their app instead of install a new one.
I know that I could change the bundle identifier for the new app but in the end I think I have so much pain, so I want avoid it.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: *"My App is written in swift ... this is a very old App"*. You have a strange definition of "very old". :)

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I think your best bet is to create a new project with the same bundle ID, so it's not a new app, and then migrate stuff you want to keep over from the old project. This will be the cleanest approach in my opinion. With that said, you'll lose any git history regarding the old project. If this is an issue then you have little choice but to modify the existing project.

Comment: To be honest, i don't want to loose my git history and i want to have the option to go back to the old version. I think the only way is to create a new branch and clean it up manually.

Comment: Yea, that sounds like the best approach then. I would just do the migration in stages so you can easily revert a chunk of changes if you mess something up.